# Is there a difference in the notation $n\in\{0,1,2,...\} and $\n=0,1,2,...$?

Tags: math, notation

I'm currently going over old questions for a group theory exam and one common question is

$$\Delta={\frac{i}{2^{n}}:i\in\Bbb{Z}, n=0,1,2,...}.$$ Prove $\Delta\leq(\Bbb{Q},+).$

Is there a difference in this question between saying $n=0,1,2,...$ and saying $n\in{0,1,2,...}$?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I think this question would be better suited for our sister site, math.stackexchange.com, as it is not related to programming or a programming problem. (It's also much better at rendering MathJAX.) That said, the n=0,1,2... means "let n take on the value of EACH of these integers" while "n is a member of {0,1,2...} means "n may be ONE of these integers."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on math.stackexchange.com.